# VMWare : How to Trace the Running Process Instructions at Guest OS?

Tags: vmware, windbg

If we assume we have only the binary, we can use windbg to drop into assembly and see what’s going on. Since windows guests run in fully emulated mode, it should be straightforward to trace in the guest.

If we want to trace what is happening in the virtualization layer, i.e.  hypervisor, it will be a bit difficult. It depends on what kind of machine we are running on. These days all machines are 64 bit with VMX enabled which allow the hypervisor to intercept guest instructions on the fly, since processor virtualization is implemented in hardware.

Since it is just a trap by which the guest drops into hypervisor it is almost impossible to tell when the guest has entered the hypervisor and when its back. However we probably will not achieve much by tracing any code in the hypervisor.
In a VMX enabled machine only page table write changes and IOPL changes will go to hypervisor. Everything else is handled in the guest itself.

For all practical application debugging windbg should be fine.

> Can we Trace the running Process(.exe) & its Instructions at guest OS using WinDbg??

Please help on this... 
Im really appreciating your time on this .. 
Thank you .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're asking if you can run windbg on a virtualized machine, then yes, it works just like it does on a physical machine.

If you want to attach to the process that is running the virtual machine itself, but look at a process that is inside of the guest os, then the answer is no.